# How to apply feature reduction using principal component analysis? (C#, Accord)

Tags: c#, matrix, pca, accord.net

I'm trying to implement PCA via the Accord framework in order to achieve dimension reduction aka feature reduction. Basically, I have one big matrix containing over 23000 features. These are all features that have been extracted from a set of documents. A really simple overview of that matrix would look like this:

```
      dog    cat    fish
doc1  0,024  0,011  0,008
doc2  0,011  0,014  0,007
doc3  0,005  0,024  0,003
doc4  0,008  0,028  0,008
doc5  0,002  0,03   0,006
```

The numbers in the matrix correspond to the Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency that we have calculated within our program. Basically this shows us how many times that term occurs in a certain document. This is useful information for us, since we will need it to determine which term in our matrix can be used as a feature for classification later on.

Since we have approximately 23000 possible features(and that # will only increase in the future) we need to reduce this to let's say +- 20 features (needed for classification later on). In order for us to realize this, we need to use something that reduces the number of features/dimensions. So we did some searching and came across the accord framework, kernel PCA, ALGLIB, etc. They're all pretty vague to us since we don't have any background in PCA and we're far from mathematicians.

So we opted to use the Accord framework since it looks simple to implement, by using the following code for testing purposes:

```
double[,] sourceMatrix = 
        {
            { 2.5,  2.4 },
            { 0.5,  0.7 },
            { 2.2,  2.9 },
            { 1.9,  2.2 },
            { 3.1,  3.0 },
            { 2.3,  2.7 },
            { 2.0,  1.6 },
            { 1.0,  1.1 },
            { 1.5,  1.6 },
            { 1.1,  0.9 }
        };

        // Creates the Principal Component Analysis of the given source
        var pca = new PrincipalComponentAnalysis(sourceMatrix, AnalysisMethod.Center);

        // Compute the Principal Component Analysis
        pca.Compute();

        // Creates a projection
        double[,] components = pca.Transform(sourceMatrix);

        for (int i = 0; i < components.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < components.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(components[i, j]);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

This code will print the matrix that resulted from the Transform method in the console. Since we didn't really understand what all the numbers mean and how they would help to reduce the features, we decided to have a look at the Components matrix in a datagridview, by using this code on the exact same matrix as the previous code example:

```
    // Creates the Principal Component Analysis of the given source
    var pca = new PrincipalComponentAnalysis(sourceMatrix, AnalysisMethod.Center);

    // Compute the Principal Component Analysis
    pca.Compute();

    // Display
    dgvPCA.DataSource = pca.Components;
    dgvPCA.Columns["Analysis"].Visible = false;
```

This returns the proportion, cumilative proportion, singular value and eigenvalue. Again, no clue.

So how do we apply this principle to reduce our matrix of +- 23000 terms to +- 20?

Comment: If you need to reduce your data from 23000 to 20 features, pass 20 as the second argument of pca.Transform, i.e.: var features = pca.Transform(sourceMatrix, 20);

Comment: There is a very simple PCA introduction to PCA called "A Tutorial on Principal Component Analysis", by Lindsay Smith, available here: http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf

I have also created a companion material explaining how to follow Lindsay's tutorial in Accord.NET: http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7463

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I did already came across some of your work during my research and it has proved helpful.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I will venture an answer that will not address all the points in your question. TL;DR : Advise at the bottom*

A **Principal Component (PC)** is simply a projection (linear combination) of a number of features, where a feature is a vector of values (generally observations or measurements) along some dimension.

For your question, the features appear to be the "Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency" for terms, with a "measurement" for each document. All features for all documents form a matrix.

What a **Principal Component Analysis (PCA)** does is to transform (or pull apart) this matrix by finding these Principal Components (that you could view as abstract features, they are also sometimes called the "hidden features"). As mentioned they are simply linear combinations of the original term vectors, as in:

```
PC1 = 0.1 * Cat + 0.001 * Dog - 0.8 * Fish ... `
PC2 = 0.0001 * Cat - 0.102 * Dog + 0.1 * Fish ...` 
...
PCN = 0.00000001 * Cat - 0.0000000001 * Dog + 0.00000000000001 * Fish ....
```

Where *N* is the same as the original number of features, and these values (0.1, 0.001, -0.8, ...) represent the **loading** of each feature on a given PC, expressing how the original term is correlated with the PC. A high positive or negative value indicates a high positive or negative correlation of the term with the PC.

An important property of the found Principal Components is that they are [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality), i.e. uncorrelated, this is nicely visually illustrated [here](http://setosa.io/ev/principal-component-analysis/).

You might try to visualize this yourself, by imagining you are looking at a 2D x-y scatter plot (x and y being the two features) with a cloud of data points (the individual observations of x and y) and try to rotate and translate the axes, while the data points stay stationary.

[image: x-y plot]

First you try to rotate the x-axis to get it to intersect the center of the cloud of points, as a linear regression line would. Next, you would move (translate) the Y-axis to the center of the points cloud. The rotated and translated positions of the X and Y axis are your principal components.

[image: rotated axes]

As you may have noticed, the Principal Components are numbered, by their **rank**. Where a component with the lowest rank explains the largest amount of **variance** in the original dataset. For the example images above, you can clearly see that "PCA Axis 1" explains far more of the variance, than "PCA Axis 2"

Generally, the number of PCs, that together explain the majority of all variance in your dataset will be much smaller than the *N* input features. This is what allows you to reduce the number of feature dimensions, by selecting the first `X` PCs that explain a sufficient amount of variance.

Another thing you can do is to look at the so-called **scores** on the PCs. This looks at each document's score on a PC, i.e. how much it contributes to a given PC.

A more thorough introductory text can be found [here](http://www.colorado.edu/geography/class_homepages/geog_4023_s11/Lecture18_PCA.pdf) and examples of some of these concepts [here](http://cosmic.mse.iastate.edu/library/pdf/pcainterpretation.pdf) and [here](http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Lectures/Lec%2017%20-%20Principal%20Component%20Analysis.pdf).

**Getting back to your question, my advice to you:**

The application of Principal Components Analysis to a complex problem such as classifying documents from a reduced set of terms is far from trivial, and requires a thorough understanding of both PCA and the classification problem you are trying to solve.

I would advise you to try to find/hire an expert in this field who can provide you with guidance and help you along the right path by asking you the questions that matter.

It would also be wise to do some more research to get a better feel for feature reduction and classification methods that are being used elsewhere to solve similar problems to the one you are tackling.

Furthermore, it would be advisable to use tools specifically tailored to this type of data analysis (e.g. SAS, Matlab, R, ...) to develop and validate your feature selection and classification methods. Once the methods are validated, if you need them to be implemented in a piece of c# software, look for the tool that best fits (which could be Accord).

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration. I'll definitely need to do some more research towards this concept and perhaps talk it over with my superiors considering the depth of this concept.

Comment: I've been looking a bit more into PCA and my understanding of it is better now. I guess I just have to find a way to retrieve which variables are reflected by a certain (or multiple) component(s), correct?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem earlier and that's what I found.
The issue of using PCA (based on accord implementation) is getting the most important features in your original data. PCA results are new component that were based on the sum of old components multiplied by their weights as Alex explained.

The problem here is that getting the weights could be a little bit tricky, so you may find it simpler and more efficient to try to solve your problem with **svm**.

accord also provides a very useful implementation, here's an example code:

```
double[][] inputs = new double[DataFiles.Count][];
int[] outputs = new int[DataFiles.Count];
//fill the inputs and outputs with your data
double c = SequentialMinimalOptimization.EstimateComplexity(inputs);


// Creates the SVM for input variables
SupportVectorMachine svm = new SupportVectorMachine(inputs:Count);

// Creates a new instance of the sparse logistic learning algorithm
var smo = new ProbabilisticDualCoordinateDescent(svm, inputs, outputs)
{
// Set learning parameters
Complexity = c,
Tolerance = 1e-5,
};
try
{
double error = smo.Run();
}
catch (ConvergenceException)
{
}
// Show feature weight importance
double[] weights = svm.Weights;
```

and please find further explanation at
https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Linear-Support-Vector-Machines